# retrive image from database and show it in div

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to retrieve image from database and show it in div in data model. I uploaded image save to images->vacancy folder. Now I want to show it when press a button. Every image name as 'vacancyid'.jpg format. I tried with following code. But I was unsuccessful.

```
<?php
require('dbconnection.php');
$sql="select * from vacancy";
$res=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($res)>0){

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
    ?>
    <script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <div class="bs-calltoaction bs-calltoaction-primary" id="jobvacancydiv<?php echo $row['vacancyid'];?>">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9 cta-contents">
                <form action="sendemail.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                <h1 class="cta-title">Its a Call To Action</h1>
                <div class="cta-desc">
                    <input type="text" value='<?= $row['catogary'];?>' readonly style="width: 75%"><br><br>
                    <input type="text" value='<?= $row['company_name'];?>' readonly style="width:    75%"><br><br>
                    <input type="text" value='<?= $row['location'];?>' readonly style="width: 75%"><br><br>
                    <input type="text" value='<?= $row['qulification'];?>' readonly style="width: 75%"><br><br>
                    <input type="text" value='<?= $row['catogary'];?>' readonly style="width: 75%"><br><br>
                    <input type="text" value='<?= $row['indate'];?>' readonly style="width: 37.5%">&nbsp;
                    <input type="text" value='<?= $row['expdate'];?>' readonly style="width: 37.5%"><br>
                    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value='<?= $row['email'];?>'><br>
                    <input type="file" name="uploaded_file" id="uploaded_file" class="text-center center-block well well-sm">
                    <input type="submit" id="btn" name="btn" class="btn btn-primary" value="Apply"></input>
                    <button id="showimg" name="showimg" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
                    <?php
                    if(isset($_POST['showimg'])){
                        ?>
                        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Image preview</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <?php
                                        //$imageData = base64_encode($row['image']);

                                        // Format the image SRC:  data:{mime};base64,{data};
                                        //$src = 'data:images/vacancy;base64,'.$imageData;
                                        $src='images/vacancy'.$row['vacancyid'].'.jpg';
                                        echo "<img src='".$src."'>";

                                        ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php

                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
                </form>

            </div>

        </div>
        </div>
    <script>
        window.setInterval(function(){

            var current = new Date();
            var expiry = new Date("<?= $row['expdate'];?>");

            if(current.getTime()>expiry.getTime()){
                $('#jobvacancydiv<?php echo $row['vacancyid'];?>').hide();
            }
            else{
                $('#jobvacancydiv<?php echo $row['vacancyid'];?>').show();
            }

        });
    </script>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
 }
else{
echo mysqli_error($conn);
}
?>
```

Comment: Is the name of your file where this form is `sendmail.php`?

Comment: sendmail.php page is used to send emails with attachments.

Comment: Now here is the point. Your modal will never show as the HTML Form POST loads the action script/page. This doesn't allow the modal on Form Page to load. Have you tried using ajax instead?

Comment: no i didnt used ajax for this

Comment: Before I post my answer, please confirm these points. You are processing the `sendemail.php` first. Once this action is complete, you plan to show Modal with the desired image in the said directory? Is that correct?

Comment: what i am trying is when click 'showimg' button show the image in modal.if user wants to send e mail, he can send emails.not want to processing the sendmail.php first.

Comment: Got it. It is a confirmation from the user before submitting the form. Wait for the answer. My answer will be with the assumption that your image is already saved in the desired location.

Comment: @MohammedAkhtarZuberi thank you for your attention for my problem

Comment: @DanithKumarasinghe is the image stored in the database?

Comment: @julekgwa yes image successfully stored in DB and server folder well.

Comment: @MohammedAkhtarZuberi i eddited previous code

Comment: Why are you calling the form in while loop?

Comment: @DanithKumarasinghe does the code below work?

Comment: @julekgwa no friend not work

Comment: can you share the code here https://codeshare.io/5DAymZ

Answer (score 0):

**Your requirement**

You want to have two buttons in your HTML Form Page. One of the buttons is `Apply` that will send an email. The second button is named as `Open Modal` that opens a Modal with an image from predefined URL. This can be from the database as well that is fetched on HTML Form Page Load. It has nothing to do with the HTML File Input Field in the Form.

**Problem You Faced**

The Modal was not showing when `Open Modal` Button was clicked.

In your code, you had your Modal in a PHP Condition that will only trigger if the below condition meets

```
if(isset($_POST['showimg'])) {
```

**Proposed Solution**

The above code will not work due to the reason that `$_POST` will only work when an information is passed to this page via `POST` method. This is only possible in action script of an HTML Form. Since your Modal is not depending on any information POSTED and should show on Button click, so simply use the below code instead.

```
<form action="sendemail.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <h1 class="cta-title">Its a Call To Action</h1>
            <div class="cta-desc">
                <input type="text" value='<?= $row['catogary'];?>' readonly style="width: 75%"><br><br>
                <input type="text" value='<?= $row['company_name'];?>' readonly style="width:    75%"><br><br>
                <input type="text" value='<?= $row['location'];?>' readonly style="width: 75%"><br><br>
                <input type="text" value='<?= $row['qulification'];?>' readonly style="width: 75%"><br><br>
                <input type="text" value='<?= $row['catogary'];?>' readonly style="width: 75%"><br><br>
                <input type="text" value='<?= $row['indate'];?>' readonly style="width: 37.5%">&nbsp;
                <input type="text" value='<?= $row['expdate'];?>' readonly style="width: 37.5%"><br>
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value='<?= $row['email'];?>'><br>
                <input type="file" name="uploaded_file" id="uploaded_file" class="text-center center-block well well-sm">
                <input type="submit" id="btn" name="btn" class="btn btn-primary" value="Apply"></input>
                <button id="showimg" name="showimg" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Image preview</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <?php
                                    $imageData = base64_encode($row['image']);

                                    // Format the image SRC:  data:{mime};base64,{data};
                                    $src = 'data:images/vacancy;base64,'.$imageData;
                                    echo "<img src='".$src."'>";
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

The only change in this code and yours is that I have taken out the Modal from all the conditions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Mohommed Akthar this also not work friend.according to my first code,model opens.but image didnt show.in your code even model dosent open.

Comment: Is it possible to share your full code along with your action script? Edit your question with full code.

Comment: Akthar how can send it.via email??

Comment: You can easily edit your code in your question. Just add the entire code along with action script.

Comment: @DanithKumarasinghe edit your question and add the code there, even though it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<?php if(isset($_POST['showimg'])){ ?>` and use `echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['image']).'"/>'; ?>`

```
<?php
require('dbconnection.php');
$sql = "select * from vacancy";
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        ?>
        <script
                src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <div class="bs-calltoaction bs-calltoaction-primary" id="jobvacancydiv<?php echo $row['vacancyid']; ?>">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9 cta-contents">
                    <form action="sendemail.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                        <h1 class="cta-title">Its a Call To Action</h1>
                        <div class="cta-desc">
                            <input type="text" value='<?= $row['catogary']; ?>' readonly style="width: 75%"><br><br>
                            <input type="text" value='<?= $row['company_name']; ?>' readonly
                                   style="width:    75%"><br><br>
                            <input type="text" value='<?= $row['location']; ?>' readonly style="width: 75%"><br><br>
                            <input type="text" value='<?= $row['qulification']; ?>' readonly style="width: 75%"><br><br>
                            <input type="text" value='<?= $row['catogary']; ?>' readonly style="width: 75%"><br><br>
                            <input type="text" value='<?= $row['indate']; ?>' readonly style="width: 37.5%">&nbsp;
                            <input type="text" value='<?= $row['expdate']; ?>' readonly style="width: 37.5%"><br>
                            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value='<?= $row['email']; ?>'><br>
                            <input type="file" name="uploaded_file" id="uploaded_file"
                                   class="text-center center-block well well-sm">
                            <input type="submit" id="btn" name="btn" class="btn btn-primary" value="Apply"></input>
                            <button id="showimg" name="showimg" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
                                    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal
                            </button>
                            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
                                 aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                                                    aria-hidden="true">×
                                            </button>
                                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Image preview</h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <?php
                                            echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['image']).'"/>';
                                            ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            window.setInterval(function () {

                var current = new Date();
                var expiry = new Date("<?= $row['expdate'];?>");

                if (current.getTime() > expiry.getTime()) {
                    $('#jobvacancydiv<?php echo $row['vacancyid'];?>').hide();
                }
                else {
                    $('#jobvacancydiv<?php echo $row['vacancyid'];?>').show();
                }

            });
        </script>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
} else {
    echo mysqli_error($conn);
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure how the image is referred here.
data:images instead try the relative path where the image is stored on server.

Comment: @shawan you mean like this '$src='images/vacancy'.$row['vacancyid'].'.jpg';
                                            echo "<img src='".$src."'>";' i tried with this.but no result

Comment: @Barry Thomas  friend i save my all images to images folder and there is another folder called vacancy inside it.all images are saved in that vacancy folder